# YOLOv6 AssertionError - Invalid Directory Path

Tags: yolo

I am trying to train my own custom dataset using YOLOv6 but the problem is I keep getting the error below:

```
Using 1 GPU for training... 
training args are: Namespace(data_path='A/data.yaml', conf_file='configs/yolov6s.py', img_size=640, batch_size=16, epochs=50, workers=8, device='0', eval_interval=20, eval_final_only=False, heavy_eval_range=50, check_images=False, check_labels=False, output_dir='./runs/train', name='yolov6s-custom', dist_url='env://', gpu_count=0, local_rank=-1, resume=False, write_trainbatch_tb=False, stop_aug_last_n_epoch=15, save_ckpt_on_last_n_epoch=-1, distill=False, distill_feat=False, quant=False, calib=False, teacher_model_path=None, temperature=20, fuse_ab=False, bs_per_gpu=32, rank=-1, world_size=1, save_dir='runs/train/yolov6s-custom3')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/YOLO_Custom/YOLOv6/tools/train.py", line 128, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/YOLO_Custom/YOLOv6/tools/train.py", line 113, in main
    trainer = Trainer(args, cfg, device)
  File "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/YOLO_Custom/YOLOv6/yolov6/core/engine.py", line 54, in __init__
    self.train_loader, self.val_loader = self.get_data_loader(args, cfg, self.data_dict)
  File "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/YOLO_Custom/YOLOv6/yolov6/core/engine.py", line 361, in get_data_loader
    train_loader = create_dataloader(train_path, args.img_size, args.batch_size // args.world_size, grid_size,
  File "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/YOLO_Custom/YOLOv6/yolov6/data/data_load.py", line 41, in create_dataloader
    dataset = TrainValDataset(
  File "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/YOLO_Custom/YOLOv6/yolov6/data/datasets.py", line 68, in __init__
    self.img_paths, self.labels = self.get_imgs_labels(self.img_dir)
  File "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/YOLO_Custom/YOLOv6/yolov6/data/datasets.py", line 220, in get_imgs_labels
    assert osp.exists(img_dir), f"{img_dir} is an invalid directory path!"
AssertionError: ./images/train is an invalid directory path!
```

My dataset path directory is in the parent YOLOv6 folder. All the folder structure follow the YOLOv6 format and all training, validation and testing images are present. I followed the official tutorial on their GitHub [Page](https://github.com/meituan/YOLOv6/blob/main/docs/Train_custom_data.md), but somehow it just can't run when I try to train it.

Below is the code used to run the training that caused such error:

```
!python tools/train.py --batch-size 16 --conf configs/yolov6s.py --data data/data.yaml --device 0 --workers 8 --batch-size 16 --epochs 50 --img-size 640 --name yolov6s-custom
```

Below is the data.yaml file located in the data folder of the parent YOLOv6 folder. (The name of dataset folder is A):
[image: data.yaml]

Comment: Do you have the images/train folder containing training images?

Comment: Could you add the line containing the path to load data?

Comment: @HSL Hope the edits provided some clear information.

Comment: And yes @Oluwafemi Sule, the images/train folder contain the training images.